# int:gateway equivalent Java DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-dsl

What is the Java DSL equivalent for int:gateway which has error channel and a default request channel.
The default request channel is input to a transformer which  sends JMS message to outbound adaptor and returns a listenable future.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
```

---

```
/**
 * Populate the {@link MessageChannel} to the new {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder}
 * chain, which becomes as a {@code requestChannel} for the Messaging Gateway(s) built
 * on the provided service interface.
 * <p>A gateway proxy bean for provided service interface is registered under a name
 * from the
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway#name()} if present
 * or from the {@link IntegrationFlow} bean name plus {@code .gateway} suffix.
 * @param serviceInterface the service interface class with an optional
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway} annotation.
 * @return new {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder}.
 */
public static IntegrationFlowBuilder from(Class<?> serviceInterface) {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-gateway